# How to add space between border line and object above the border [html]

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add space/margin between the gray borderline and the three images outside the border(right above the gray dashed borderline) Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>The Maze Runner - FanPage</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
    body {
      font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background: black;
    }
    #example1 {
      border: 5px dashed DarkOliveGreen;
      background: white;
      padding: 15px;
      background-clip: border-box;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    #exampleh {text-align: center;}
    #example2 {
      border: 5px dashed DarkGray;
      background: white;
      padding: 15px;
      background-clip: border-box;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
      border-spacing: 5px 1rem;
    }
    #example21 {font-size: 20px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <p>
      <style>
        img {display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
      </style>
      <img src="https://www.whats-on-netflix.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/maze-runner.jpg" alt="The Maze Runner series" class="center" style="width:65%;"/>
    </p>
    
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/be/The_Maze_Runner_poster.jpg/220px-The_Maze_Runner_poster.jpg" align="left" style="width:33.33%;"/>
    <img src="https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/image_9435b9ce.jpeg" alt="Maze Runner: The Scorch Trials" align="left" style="width:33.33%;"/>
    <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/91/80/65/9180651eb1ce73d594d8b26bbcf54c60.jpg" alt="Maze Runner: The Death Cure" align="right" style="width:33.33%;"/>

    <div id="example2">
      <div id="exampleh">
        <h1>5 Reasons To Watch Maze Runner series</h1></div>
          <div id="example21">
            <ol>
              <li>Love</li>
              <li>Love</li>
              <li>Love</li>
              <li>Love</li>
              <li>Love</li>
            </ol>

  </body>
</html>
```

I tried adding `border-spacing` in the  `<style>example2` but did not work. I also tried something like `margin-top` but did not work either. Can someone help me, please?
Thank you.

Comment: Is that your whole example? If so you're missing closing tags and have malformed html which is your most likely culprit as a guess unless you'd like to edit your question with a working example (preferably using the Snippet Editor - the button on the top of the text editor with `<>` on it) so we can reproduce your issue visually as well. Cheers

Comment: You just wrap your images into one Block element and make sure that should have 100% width. That will work as you expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use **float** on the image. You should wrap your three images inside a div and then use **flex** on the main image div. Check out my example below:

```css
body {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: black;
        }

        #example1 {
            border: 5px dashed DarkOliveGreen;
            background: white;
            padding: 15px;
            background-clip: border-box;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        #exampleh {
            text-align: center;
        }

        #example2 {
            border: 5px dashed DarkGray;
            background: white;
            padding: 15px;
            background-clip: border-box;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
            border-spacing: 5px 1rem;
            margin-top: 10px;
        }

        #example21 {
            font-size: 20px;
        }

        img {
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .image-items {
            display: flex;
        }

        .img-box {
            padding: 0 5px;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>The Maze Runner - FanPage</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <p>
        <img src="https://www.whats-on-netflix.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/maze-runner.jpg"
            alt="Main Image">
    </p>
    <div class="image-items">
        <div class="img-box">
            <img
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/b/be/The_Maze_Runner_poster.jpg/220px-The_Maze_Runner_poster.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="img-box">
            <img src="https://lumiere-a.akamaihd.net/v1/images/image_9435b9ce.jpeg"
                alt="Maze Runner: The Scorch Trials" />
        </div>
        <div class="img-box">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/91/80/65/9180651eb1ce73d594d8b26bbcf54c60.jpg"
                alt="Maze Runner: The Death Cure" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="example2">
        <div id="exampleh">
            <h1>5 Reasons To Watch Maze Runner series</h1>
        </div>
        <div id="example21">
            <ol>
                <li>Love</li>
                <li>Love</li>
                <li>Love</li>
                <li>Love</li>
                <li>Love</li>
            </ol>

</body>

</html>
```